# Best battery type for outdoor equipment

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

As per the title, I'm looking for a battery that can be left outdoors (in an enclosure) and withstand a wide range of temperatures, from around -5 to 40/45 °C.

It will be kept under charge constantly as a backup system (I will set it up so it stops charging at around 90% and keep it topped off when it drops too low).

Doesn't need to be big, double or triple A should be good enough.

I tried looking up the various types but I can't really determine which one I should use, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Lead acid "car battery" is the obvious choice - they are big and bulky but designed to be charged "on the fly". You can forget about Li/Ion chemistries since they can't be charged during negative temperatures. NiMH doesn't like to be charged until as close to depleted as possible.

Comment: @Lundin well, battery heating systems are a thing; really depends on availability of power in scenarios where you want to charge. Also, and this is my shortcoming, really don't know the current state of the market on the different LiIon technologies compared to Pb batteries at the lower end of the temperature scale, but -5 °C doesn't really sound that problematic to me for most LiIons these days (or else a lot of people would have a lot more problems with their phones and cars)

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's only a problem when charging, not during use. How many people charge their phone outdoors during winter? Most chargers shut off if the battery temperature is below 0°C.

Comment: hm, interesting. I guess it's not very linear how ion diffusion happens when charging, skimming the relevant literature there. Question is whether that can be avoided by simply making sure that the charger heats up the device in the case it needs to charge during below-freezing idle time. (self discharge also drops significantly when it's cold, so you should never have to top up in winter unless the device was actively using power)

Comment: I bet the answer depends on your budget. If you have a lot of money for very exotic batteries, or permits for radioactive thermal generators, you don't have to settle for cheap available consumer lithium ion batteries. I think you should define the need better, or otherwise this is just what should I buy type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best choice is lead acid, or a “car battery”.  You can get them in much smaller sizes than for cars, and can get 6volt versions.  They tolerate wide temperature fluctuations reasonably well.
Lead acid batteries are the chemistry that really prefer to stay at fully charged without degrading so no need to program a charger to stop at 90%.

lithium ion will degrade quickly if left sitting fully, or mostly fully charged AND degrade very quickly when charged at or below 0 degrees Celsius.

NiMh will degrade quickly if not cycled relatively deeply; so they do better if you fully, or almost fully discharge them most cycles.

The older NiCad might work for you, they come in the double AA size, and actually can tolerate the cold better than most other batteries.  I believe that they would also do better if cycled more fully, but you can’t win them all. They also have the lowest energy density of the four.

Edison batteries were mentioned and could be used, but they are harder to find in the size you are looking for.

Comment: NiCd are illegal to use in most countries nowadays though.

Comment: @Lundin - there is still a large variety available in the sizes the OP wants on both the U.S. and Canadian Amazon sites!

Comment: Are they _legal_ to use in North America though? I think they are illegal in most of the world by now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried looking into all the options listed here and out of all of them, using a car battery seems the most sensible option. While there are better choices and other workarounds I could use, the final cost (both in terms of time and money) would end up being way too high for the project I'm trying to make.

Comment: @Lundin - NiCd are legal for use in North America, a recycling fee has been added to their price and the end consumer is expected to bring the dead battery to the appropriate recycling facility.  There are many stores where they can be found for many different applications.  The EU is the only place that banned NiCd and they allowed exceptions for medical devices, emergency lighting, and UPS.

Comment: "The EU is the only place that banned NiCd" Umm... no. https://getenviropass.com/rohs-compliant-products-worldwide/  It's the American world-view that's skewed here, in fact North America are 18 years behind the rest of the world. That link also claims they are illegal in California.

Comment: I’m not interested in an argument here, but that website includes all countries except North America as “banned” yet a random search reveals that you can still buy a wide variety of NiCd batteries in Japan, so I suspect they may available in other countries too; although they really should stop making them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a rugged, long lasting battery you might look at [nickel-iron cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel%E2%80%93iron_battery) (also known as Edison cells).

They handle extreme temperatures and repeated deep discharging well, and can be continuously charged. With proper care they can last for decades.

They have some disadvantages though, they have lower energy density than other battery types, charge and discharge slower, and have a high self-discharge rate. You also need a charger that is designed for them.

Comment: Edison cells are also very hard to find, expensive, and most are very large, not the smaller AAA or AA size the OP is looking for.